# A target depends on dependency of another target

Tags: makefile

I would like to let a target `A` depend on all dependencies of another target `B`, but not `B` itself.

My real project is not in C. I just use C to give an example.
I would like to save output messages during compilation of `a.c` in an output file `a.out`.
So the output file `a.out` should depend on dependency of normal compilation target `a.o`, but not `a.o` itself.
I would like to take the advantage that dependency of `a.o` can be generated automatically
and copy it to `a.out` automatically.

```
a.o : a.c
    gcc a.c -o a.o

# a.out should depend on a.h b.h c.h, too. I would like to copy it from generated dependency below.
a.out : a.c
    gcc a.c -o a.o > a.out

# Automatically generated
a.o : a.h b.h c.h
```

Comment: There is no way to do this from within make itself.  There's no introspection that allows you to retrieve the dependencies of another target.  Since the dependencies are auto-generated, you could modify the auto-generate operation so that it adds the other target.  For example have it generate `a.out a.o : a.h b.h c.h` instead.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this functionality. It will help suggest a solution that is relevant